# ng-click not firing when button is clicked

Tags: angularjs

Can someone tell me when i run the below Angular code and when i click on the button it does not load the page. Even i do a simple alert it doesnt seem to work.

Any idea what i must be doing wrong here?

**JavaScript**

```
    var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {controller:Test, templateUrl:'test/part1'}).
          when('/details', {controller:Test, templateUrl:'test/part2'}).
          otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
    });

    function grab ($scope, $location) {
         $scope.reserve = function (id) {
         $location.path('/details/'+id);
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <button id="btt" type="button" ng-click="grab(2)">Click to grab</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head something like:

```
 var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

        app.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
              when('/', {controller:Test, templateUrl:'test/part1'}).
              when('/details', {controller:Test, templateUrl:'test/part2'}).
              otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
        });

    app.controller('Test', ['$scope', '$location', function Test($scope, $location) {
        $scope.grab = function (id) {{
             $location.path('/details/'+id);
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Where is the controller?

Function grab should have been in the controller and also you cannot call grab outside of the $scope. So

- grab must be refactored to `$scope.grab = function($location)`
- moved inside the controller 'Test'

Answer (score 2):

please define a controller for the body and then add the function grab to $scope

```
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">

        app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){
                 $scope.grab = function(id) { 
                     $location.path('/details/'+id);
                 }
        }])
```